# Setting a Loading Screen Within the Theme.res CodenameOne

Tags: java, intellij-idea, codenameone

I'm trying to make a loading screen that pops up for my app for purely cosmetic reasons. I have read these two articles https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/InfiniteContainer.html https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/InfiniteProgress.html 
but neither have really addressed what I want to create. I want to create a small loading symbol (infinite progress) on top of a logo and then have it disappear after a certain amount of time and display the rest of the app (this whole operation preferably built in to my theme). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The infinite progress is meant for in-app progress. You just want a splash screen which you can do like this:

```
Form myForm = new Form(new BorderLayout());
myForm.add(CENTER, new ScaleImageLabel(myLogoImage));
myForm.add(SOUTH, new InfiniteProgress());
myForm.show();
UITimer.timer(4000, false, myForm, () -> showNextForm());
```

Comment: Hello, everything seems to be working except the last line of code (UITimer.schedule). Schedule is highlighted with the error "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context". It also highlights showNextForm with "cannot resolve method".

Comment: `showNextForm()` is what you need to implement to show the next form... Yes you are correct, schedule is wrong it should have been `timer` fixing this now.